# How To See All Field Names In SFDC Developer Console

Tags: salesforce

How can one see all the fields of an object using the SFDC Developer Console?

I looked at this Salesforce YouTube Video at
http://www.salesforce.com/_app/video/developer/help/developer_console.jsp However, I did not see a way to get to a list of the object fields through the Repository tab Object selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*finneycanhelp* is correct.

In developer console:

1. Click on Repository tab
2. Click on Object in Setup Entity Type Window
3. Double click on any object in the Entities Window
4. You will find the list of all the fields for that particular object.

Hope this is more clearer.

Comment: I just went to look for this tab, and it wasn't there.  The new path is File menu > Open > Objects > pick an Entity/object.

Answer (score 1):

If one double clicks on the Object entity, the names of the fields are shown.